Missing /usr/bin/python3
I'm missing the python3 binary in /usr/bin/.
which python3 outputs /home/d4rkc10ud/anaconda3/bin/python3
sudo apt install python3 outputs python3 is already the newest version (3.12.3-0ubuntu1).
sudo apt install python3-dev outputs python3-dev is already the newest version (3.12.3-0ubuntu1).
A python3 file exists in /usr/local/bin that links to a python3.12 file in the same directory.
I'm running Kubuntu 24.04 on my machine. I'd really appreciate any help.
UPDATE:
file /usr/bin/python3 outputs /usr/bin/python3: broken symbolic link to python3.12
Maybe creating a symbolic link from /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/local/bin/python3.12 would help? I'm fairly new to linux so I'm afraid to just try it and mess things up more.

please don't start making such symlinks, out of guessing. Before you were using anaconda, did you manually install any python things system-wide, any other way than with apt? It's not usual that a python installation gets so messed up, so we're really left to wonder whether you'd have any idea what could have caused this.

for example, there really should not be a python3 in /usr/local – that points to your installing a non-packaged python. When did that happen?

You need to reinstall python3-minimal, after cleaning things up:
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/py3compile
sudo apt reinstall python3-minimal

Since the /usr/bin/python3 symlink is broken, you also need to reinstall python3.12-minimal:
sudo apt reinstall python3.12-minimal


That returns the following error: E: Internal Error, No file name for python3-minimal:amd64
I tried running sudo apt install python3-minimal and that py3compile: not found. py3compile seems to depend on the missing #! /usr/bin/python3 file.

@MedhanshGarg this sounds a bit like you're running sudo apt… from within an conda environment. don't do that.

@MedhanshGarg you should remove the dangling symlink first, at least; see the updated answer.

I tried running the command outside the conda environment after running conda deactivate, still the same issues.
I ran the rm command that you suggested. That seemed to remove the symlink and the py3compile file.
I then ran the second command which threw an error saying E: Internal Error, No file name for python3-minimal:amd64.
So I tried sudo apt install python3-minimal which seemed to run without any errors but it didn't seem to install python3.
So I then retried the reinstall command which recreated the py3compile file and the broken symlink.

Should I try ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-optimizations to install python from source into /usr/bin/?

No, whatever you do, don’t install anything other than the system’s Python packages in /usr/bin. You need to reinstall python3.12-minimal too, see the updated answer.
